# Log4j entries going to WebLogic managed server out file

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic

Some of my log4j entries are going to the managed server out file. This isn't happening all the time.  My log4j is set up with INFO for everything, but when it does go to the out file, I all the DEBUG is getting logged.  What could be causing this?

Here's the log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- -->
<!-- Log4j Configuration -->
<!-- -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- $Id: log4j.xml,v 1.13.2.3 2003/05/02 00:53:12 slaboure Exp $ -->
<!--
        | For more configuration infromation and examples see the Jakarta Log4j
        | owebsite: http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j
-->
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
        debug="false">
        <!-- =================Appenders for CSF=================-->
        <appender name="CSF_FILE"
                class="gov.va.integration.core.logging.ExceptionCRRollingFileAppender">
<!--            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" /> -->
<!--            <param name="File" value="${logFile.location}" /> -->
                <param name="File" value="./servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/myapp/myapp.log" />
                <param name="Append" value="true" />
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="50000KB" />
                <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-5p][%t](%F:%L): %c - %m\r%n" />
                </layout>
        </appender>
        <!-- =================Appenders for Events=================-->
        <appender name="EVENT_FILE"
                class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
                <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
                <param name="File" value="" />
                <param name="Append" value="true" />
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="500KB" />
                <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1" />
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <!--=================End Appenders for Event================= -->
        <!-- ============================== -->
        <!-- Append messages to the console -->
        <!-- ==============================-->
        <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
                <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
<!--            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" /> -->
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <!--  The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
                        <param name="ConversionPattern"
                                value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-5p]: myapp %c - %m\r%n" />

                        <param name="ConversionPattern"
                                value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ} %-5p]: myapp %c - %m\r%n" />
                </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="JSR77" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
                <param name="Append" value="false" />
                <param name="File" value="/log/jsr77.log" />
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <param name="ConversionPattern"
                                value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
                </layout>
        </appender>
        <!-- ====================== -->
        <!-- More Appender -->
        <!-- ====================== -->
        <!-- Buffer events and log them asynchronously -->
        <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
                <appender-ref ref="CSF_FILE" />
                <appender-ref ref="EVENT_FILE" />
        </appender>
        <!-- ================ -->
        <!-- Limit categories -->
        <!-- ================ -->
        <!-- Limit categories to INFO
                <category name="">
                <priority value="INFO"/>
                </category>
        -->
        <!--
                RULES for logging DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL.
        -->
        <!-- tested and run
        <category name="*" additivity="false">
                <priority value="ERROR" />
        </category>
  -->
        <!--
                Decrease the priority threshold
                <category name="">
                <priority value="DEBUG"/>
                </category>
        -->


        <!-- Setup the Root category -->
        <root>
                <priority value="INFO"/>
                <appender-ref ref="CSF_FILE" />
        </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: show us the `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file

Comment: @san, I just added it.